# How can I hide two lines y = 6 and y = -4 in this picture?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to hide  `y = 6` and `y = -4`. I tried `line width=0pt`, but not correct. How can I hide that lines? And how can I reduce my code?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    declare function={Y(\x)=(\x-1)/(\x+1);},
    axis lines = center,
    axis line style = very thick,
every axis x label/.style={
at={(ticklabel* cs:1.06)},anchor=east},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        domain=-6:8,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=6,
        xmin=-6,
        xmax=4,
        xticklabels={},yticklabels={},
       unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    width=10cm,
    grid=major,
    grid style={gray!30}
    ]
\addplot [name path=A,blue, very thick,samples=100] {Y(x)};
\addplot [red, very thick] {1};
\addplot[name path=B,line width=0pt] {-4};
\addplot[name path=C,line width=0pt] {6};
       \node at (axis cs:-0.25, -0.25) {$O$} ;
     \addplot [black, mark = *] coordinates {(-1, 1)} ;

\addplot[pattern=north east lines] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-0.55:4},];

\addplot[pattern=north east lines] fill between[of=A and C,soft clip={domain=-6:-1},];
       \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant option is `draw=none`, so

```
\addplot [name path=B, draw=none] {-4};
```

adds a path named `B` that you can refer to but draws nothing visible.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    declare function={Y(\x)=(\x-1)/(\x+1);},
    axis lines = center,
    axis line style = very thick,
    every axis x label/.style={
      at={(ticklabel* cs:1.06)},anchor=east},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    domain=-6:8,
    ymin=-4,
    ymax=6,
    xmin=-6,
    xmax=4,
    xticklabels={},yticklabels={},
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    width=10cm,
    grid=major,
    grid style={gray!30}
    ]
\addplot [name path=A,blue, very thick,samples=100] {Y(x)};
\addplot [red, very thick] {1};
\addplot [name path=B, draw=none] {-4};
\addplot [name path=C, draw=none] {6};
\node at (axis cs:-0.25, -0.25) {$O$} ;
\addplot [black, mark = *] coordinates {(-1, 1)} ;
\addplot[pattern=north east lines] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-0.55:4},];
\addplot[pattern=north east lines] fill between[of=A and C,soft clip={domain=-6:-1},];
       \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally, you have set `pgfplots` to `compat=1.9`.  The current version is `1.15`.